# trying to get the money members from table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have

member table

```
member_Id
Last name
first name
postcode
reference
```

another table memberstomships

```
member_Id
membertomship_lastdate
membertomship_paymentmethod  column with values money  
member_id
membershipstatusid
membershipoptionid
```

another table membershipstatustype table

```
membershipstatusid
memberstatustype_name
```

another table membershiptype

```
membershiptype_id
membershiptype_name
```

another table membershipoption

```
membershiptype_id
membershipoptionid
```

I want to get the lastname and firstname and memberstatustype_name  and  membershiptype_name and  membertomship_lastdate for members those who have   membertomship_paymentmethod is money

can any one help me out pls....

many thanks.

Comment: is it possible to get the lastname and firstname and memberstatustype_name and membershiptype_name and membertomship_lastdate for members those who have membertomship_paymentmethod is money

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
SELECT 
  member.lastname,
  member.firstname
  membershipstatustype.memberstatustype_name
  membershiptype.membershiptype_name
  memberstomships.membertomship_lastdate
FROM 
  member
  INNER JOIN memberstomships ON member .member_id = memberstomships.memberid
  INNER JOIN membershipstatustype ON memberstomships.membershipstatusid = membershipstatustype.membershipstatusid 
  INNER JOIN membershiptype ON membershipstatustype.membershiptype_name = membershiptype.membershiptype_name 
WHERE
  UCASE(memberstomships.membertomship_paymentmethod) = 'MONEY'
```

Comment: ya is it possible not to define the a , b, c directly using table names

Answer (score 4):

Do it yourself! here are the tutorials on how to use SQL joins:

http://w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

http://www.tizag.com/sqlTutorial/sqljoin.php

“Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime.”

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
SELECT  Member.LastName,  Memebr.FirstName, memberstatustype_name, membershiptype_name, membertomship_lastdate,
FROM Members
 LEFT JOIN  Memberstomships
ON Memberstomships.member_Id = Members .member_Id
LEFT JOIN  membershipstatustype
ON membershipstatustype .membershipstatusid = Memberstomships.membershipstatusid 
LEFT JOIN membershipoption 
ON membershipoption .membershipoptionid = memberstomships.membershipoptionid 
LEFT JOIN  membershiptype
ON membershipstatustype .membershiptype_id = membershipoption .membershiptype_id
WHERE membertomship_paymentmethod =  'money'
```

Answer (score 0):

Is better if you use the **LIKE** operator to compare strings.

P.S. Your tables and fields name are really hard to read. Correct them.

Comment: Is the same. Is better if you chose to use shorter names. It's very difficult to read and write code with these names.